# Is there any way to run docker command in airflow dag?

Tags: docker, airflow

I am trying to run docker container in airflow.
however, DockerOperator cannot be imported due to env problem. so I am trying to run docker container with BashOperator.

this is a sample operator witch I am trying to run

```
run_model_op = BashOperator(
                task_id=f'run_model_GPU{gpu}',
                env={"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":gpu},
                bash_command='docker images',
                append_env=True,
                dag=dag,
            )
```

and the final graph looks like this, using multiple gpus in node running parallel

```
start - run_model_op(gpu0)- run_model_op_3(gpu0)...  
      - run_model_op_1(gpu1)- run_model_op_2(gpu1)...  
      ...
```

however, running this dag raises this error

```
[2023-04-07, 22:29:19 KST] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'docker images']
[2023-04-07, 22:29:19 KST] {taskinstance.py:1909} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 185, in execute
    result = self.subprocess_hook.run_command(
  File "/home/airflow/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/subprocess.py", line 76, in run_command
    self.sub_process = Popen(
  File "/home/airflow/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/home/airflow/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1626, in _execute_child
    env_list.append(k + b'=' + os.fsencode(v))
  File "/home/airflow/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 806, in fsencode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

what can be a problem in this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES value should be str, not int. It's just enough to wrap it with the str method:

```
...
env={"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":str(gpu)},
...
```

Comment: that saved me a lot of time. thanks!